# Best way to give a form label a description in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

I'm trying to give a label in a Rails form a description

[image].

This is the way I have implemented it:

```
<%= f.label(:status) %>
<p class="description">Is this a draft or the final update?</p>
<%= f.select(:status, [["Draft", "Draft"],["Final", "Final"]], hide_label: true)     %>
```

I can't help thinking this is an untidy way of doing it. Is there a Rails helper or label option for giving a label a description?

If you know a better way of achieiving this result, it'd really tidy up my code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use  tag and then style it the way you want. 
You can check it here : http://www.w3schools.com/TAgs/tag_dl.asp